# How can I convert a URL query string into a list of tuples using Python?

Tags: python, url, parsing

I am struggling to convert a url to a nested tuple.

```
# Convert this string
str = 'http://somesite.com/?foo=bar&key=val'

# to a tuple like this:
[(u'foo', u'bar'), (u'key', u'val')]
```

I assume I need to be doing something like:

```
 url = 'http://somesite.com/?foo=bar&key=val'
 url = url.split('?')
 get = ()
 for param in url[1].split('&'):
     get = get + param.split('=')
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module.

> This module defines a standard
>   interface to break Uniform Resource
>   Locator (URL) strings up in components
>   (addressing scheme, network location,
>   path etc.), to combine the components
>   back into a URL string, and to convert
>   a “relative URL” to an absolute URL
>   given a “base URL.”

Here is an example:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl

url = 'http://somesite.com/?foo=bar&key=val'
print parse_qsl(urlparse(url)[4])
```

**Output:**

```
[('foo', 'bar'), ('key', 'val')]
```

In this example I first use the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) function to parse the entire URL then I use the [`parse_qsl`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) function to break the querystring (the fifth element returned from `urlparse`) into a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer was really informative and helpful. A less adept way to grab those params would be with a regular expression--something like this:

import re

```
re_param = re.compile(r'(?P<key>w\+)=(?P<value>w\+)')

url = 'http://somesite.com/?foo=bar&key=val''
params_list = re_param.findall(url)
```

Also, in your code it looks like you're trying to concatenate a list and tuple--

```
for param in url[1].split('&'):
    get = get + param.split('=')
```

You created get as a tuple, but str.split returns a list. Maybe this would fix your code:

```
for param in url[1].split('&'):
    get = get + tuple(param.split('='))
```